# Are Latin "laevus" (left-hand side), Croatian "lijevo" (leftwards), and English "left" (in the sense "side") related?

Tags: etymology

Are Latin "laevus" (left-hand side), Croatian "lijevo" (leftwards), and English "left" (in the sense "side") related? They definitely look like they could be related, but [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/13hjk4t/comment/jk76d4c/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) claims they are not.

Comment: Did you try looking it up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Laevus* and *lijevo* are, but "left" is not. The first two come from PIE **leh₂-i-wos*, from **leh₂-* "be hidden" (compare *lateō* and λανθάνω). The latter probably comes from PIE **lewp-* "break, separate" (compare лупить "thrash"), though this is harder to be sure of because there are fewer attested cognates. But in general, it's very uncommon for English F to correspond to Latin V; English F generally comes from PIE **p*.